# How do you get Process id of thread?

Tags: c++, process, thread-safety

I wanna get thread id of chrome.  I don't want to get the thread id of my window.  I want to get the thread id of other windows.  What function should i use? and is processor id same as thread id?

Comment: Chrome consists of several threads, in fact it consists for several processes (e.g. one for each tab). Not sure what you want to achieve...

Comment: Well.. I wanna set a hook that will get me keyboard messages.

Comment: I can think of several reasons for wanting to do that, but most are nefarious.

Comment: Do you want to obtain a thread ID or a process ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the thread id of a window by using the GetWindowThreadProcessId function. It takes two arguments, the first is a handle to the window and the second is the process id. The function returns the thread id. Take a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info. You can get the handle to a window by using the [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. (I'm assuming you are on a windows machine).

I think by 'processor', you mean process. process id is not the same as thread id. Every process may have many threads inside each having their own IDs. By sending a parameter to the second argument of the GetWindowThreadProcessId function you can get the process id and it's information.

In the following code win_thread_id would get the thread id of the window that the cursor is on at the time of execution:

```
HWND handle;
POINT *point = new POINT();
GetCursorPos(point);
handle = WindowFromPoint(*point);

//Get the thread ID for the window from the handle
DWORD win_thread_id;
win_thread_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, NULL);
```

NOTE: I didn't test the code, and by the way you should include windows.h

Comment: You must send an empty LPDWORD variable to the GetWindowThreadProcessId function's second parameter. It will fill it with the process id.

Comment: Is there better way to get handle of window?

Comment: There are a couple of ways. Maybe you'd like the FindWindow function. Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the platform in your question.  Assuming this is Windows, you can start your research here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847(v=VS.85).aspx

In short, you'll need to enumerate processes and threads (or alternatively, enumerate windows on the desktop) and then you can open handles to the appropriate resources.